# Error CS2001: Source file MyProfile.cshtml.g.cs could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a problem with my project which was developed with .net Core SDK 2.2.

It was working but after operating system upgrade (Mac OS X Catalina) my project throws this error for each view pages.

```
/Users/myUser/Projects/FilterApp/FilterApp.Two/CSC: Error CS2001: Source file 
'/Users/myUser/Projects/FilterApp/FilterApp.Two/obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/netcoreapp2.2/
Razor/Views/Home/MyProfile.cshtml.g.cs' could not be found. (CS2001) (FilterApp.Two)
```

I couldn't resolve this problem after trying many things on the internet.

Here is my SDK List

- 2.1.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
- 2.2.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
- 2.2.207 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
- 3.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
- 3.1.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

Comment: When did you meet this error?If it is a compile time error, please check whether the account used to build the application or run the application have access to that specific file. If it is runtime error, could you provide logs which could be helpful to resolve your issue.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to build project. These are not runtime error. Maybe it is about permissions. I'll check.

Answer (score 2):

I have a problem with my  net core mvc razor project which was developed with .net Core SDK 2.2.

This problem only appears when dotnet core mvc razor ,my project throws this error for each view pages.

I think the problem is  [msbuild](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild)  error.

on window 10, in rider 2019.3 or vs2019, I don't have this problem.

on mac ,in rider 2019.3 or vs2019 ,I have this problem too.

```
GuodeMacBook-Pro:Code sopcce $ msbuild /version
用于 Mono 的 Microsoft (R) 生成引擎版本 16.3.0-ci
版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。
```

I've tried to walk around by adding this line to the csproj file and it built successfully.

Don't ask me why,

I don't know.

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

my Web.csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <BuildDir>Build</BuildDir>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

ps:

- [razor-pages doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the obj folder, then rebuild the solution.

Comment: I tried this many times. It couldn't help me. But it windows it is working without any problem.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows. I have solved one of the error by renaming file, but it did not helped with the other file, so I still do not have any workaround how to fix this issue.